# Writing a user-function to return column position, column name, mode and class for every variable

Tags: r, class, dataframe, mode

I need to write a user-defined function that, when applied to a data frame, will return the column position, the column name, the mode, and the class for each variable. I am able to create one that returns mode and class, but I keep getting errors when I include the position/name. I have been doing this,

```
myFunction <- function(x) { 
    data.frame(mode(x), class(x))
  }
data.frame(names(myData), myFunction(myData))
```

and it returns the correct info, but it doesn't combine it into a single function I need. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Adding some newlines, spaces and indendation makes your code much more readable, I edited your code as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine it as follows:

```
myFunction <- function(x)
   data.frame(mode(x), class(x), cname=names(x), cpos=1:ncol(x))
```

Comment: @Kara, since you seem to be a new user, I suggest you read the [**SO about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to get to know the format of SO.